# How to add access rules using .NET roles and authorization at the page level

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-3.5, authorization, roles

I have a website in .Net 3.5 that uses membership, roles, and authorization.

I created 2 roles: Default and SpecialPermissions

I have all users who are logged in are Default, but a select few are added to the SpecialPermissions role.

I have a folder called AdditionalStats and I want all of the files in that folder except one be allowed by SpecialPermissions and denied by everyone else.

```
AdditionalStats folder
    File1 - allow only SpecialPermissions
    File2 - allow only SpecialPermissions
    File3 - allow Default and SpecialPermissions
```

Is there a simple way to add this to web.config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<location path="Page1.aspx">

<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>

<location path="Page2.aspx">

<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

is allowed I was incorrect

Comment: Where do I specify the url I want to add and deny stuff too?

Comment: you can have a web config in each directory as well with just a basic tag  ,  I updated the post to show you to specify a page

Comment: Can you have multiple locations in the base web.config?

Comment: no but you can have multiple folders is the "work around" and the path can be a path instead of a page

Comment: you can also use inheritance http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7(v=vs.100).aspx